# having trouble with .fadeOut() .delay() and .fadeIn() in my contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fade out my contact form then add a delay of 2000 before fading in the success message when the submit click event and success call are activated. My problem is however that when the thank you message/div doesn't seem to wait for the delay, instead displaying straight away. Can anyone advise me why this might be happening?

The 2 lines of code are as follows:

```
$('#contact-form').fadeOut().delay(2000);
$('#thank-you').fadeIn('slow');
```

Thanks in advance
Kyle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the callback of fadeout to trigger the show of thank-you

```
$('#contact-form').fadeOut( function() {
      $('#thank-you').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
});
```